# Error with GiNaC library

Tags: c++, compilation, libraries, hyperlink

I'm making a C++ program available under Linux, Mac and Windows environments, respectively.

It uses GiNaC library.

It works fine under Linux and Mac environment.

However, I failed to build it under Windows environment.

I used precompiled GiNaC files including header, library and executable files downloaded from http://theor.jinr.ru/~varg/web/proj/ginac/woe32/ .

The following is the console message, and bold text represents the error message.

> 08:19:09 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project
>   metapro **** Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC"
>   that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway. Info:
>   Internal Builder is used for build g++
>   "-LC:\Users\yoons\Documents\ginac-1.4.4-cln-1.2.2-2587288a-gmp-4.2.4-i586-mingw32msvc\opt\ginac\lib\"
>   "-LC:\vcpkg\packages\gsl_x86-windows\lib"
>   "-LC:\Users\yoons\Documents\boost_1_70_0\stage\lib" -o
>   myproject.exe a.o b.o main.o c.o d.o e.o -lginac
>   -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas  c.o: In function `Z7ordmetaSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EEPPdS9_iiiS5_':
>
> **C:\Users\yoons\eclipse-workspace\metapro\Debug/../c.cpp:53:
>   undefined reference to
>   `GiNaC::symbol::symbol(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, unsigned int)'**
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> 08:19:10 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.221ms)

A strange thing is that the error occurred only 'symbol' type not others such as 'ex' or other functions provided by GiNaC package.

If anyone knows the answer, please let me know.

Sora

Comment: From the error message: "Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway." That doesn't sound very promising right? Maybe check your build environment and the docs of this windows port.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. That message appeared after I changed the compiler from MinGW32 to MinGW64 to solve an error about multiple definition.